# Can't find these options in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

This is my version of Visual Studio:
[image]

My project is a C++ CLR/CLI Winforms.
I had to change the namespace of my project then I'm having issues with the resource .resx file. According to other answers out there I have to change the `Custom Tool Namespace` in the resource .resx property to my custom namespace but I can't find such an option like this:

[image]

**No Build Action nor Custom Tool Namespace, this is what I get instead:**

[image]

[image]

It seems older and newer versions of Visual Studio have it but not my version, some people tell to change specific values in .cs, .csproj or .vbproj files, but my project doesn't have it at all.

**EDIT:**
I migrated my project to Visual Studio 2019 Community, my project got converted to 2019 but it didn't help, still same resource resx property so I'm not able to change the namespace linked to my resource resx file. I've been searching for hours I don't see any answer related to this issue though, I'd appreciate if anyone could solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, as you can see in my picture example, there's `Resource Logical Name`, set that to your custom namespace, for example: `MyNameSpace.MyResourceFileName.resources`

Remember it has to end with `.resources` like in the example.

**Attention:** Do not confuse ResourceFileName with ClassName, you might get it wrong when setting `Resource Logical Name` for localized resource files.